# Displaying or Hiding Metadata on Page from WP Dashboard

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called "Celeb". This CPT contains two Taxonomy terms as "Men" and "Women".Each Post has two metadata as "Name" and "Age".

[image]

Now I would Like to add a "Visibility" checkbox to WordPress CPanel to enable or disabe displaying the "Age" metadata on the page based on the Terms.
For example I would like to Hide the Age for all post under the ONLY "Women" Taxonomy term when the checkbox has been checked or vice versa.Can you please let me know how I can do this?

Update:

[image]

[image]

Comment: does someone has any idea about this, please?

Comment: Ok I tried to illustrate what I mean by adding some new images! hopefully helps